# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token during logging with gmail in java

Tags: java, gwt, oauth-2.0

I want to integrate login with gmail as well as login with facebook on our website, so that without a new signup user can create his/her account on our website. Its a gwt with java based website. I have tried some codes and getting error **java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token** and I am totally unaware why i am getting this error.
 I have used [thisdoc](http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2014/11/login-with-google-with-java-tutorial.html#.VZ5IzV-qocR) for code. Any help in why actually I am getting this error. have i missed something? any help in it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it's Unauthorized(401)..You must have to give **client_id** and **client_secret** and also each request to the Gmail API requires an **access token**.

try this code at your redirected method

```
        String code = request.getParameter("code");

        String urlParameters = "code=" + code + "&client_id="
                + CLIENT_ID + "&client_secret="
                + CLIENT_SECRET + "&redirect_uri="
                + REDIRECT_GMAIL_URI
                + "&grant_type=authorization_code";

        URL url = new URL("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                urlConn.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(urlParameters);
        writer.flush();

        String line, outputString = "";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlConn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            outputString += line;
        }
        JsonObject json = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(outputString);
        String access_token = json.get("access_token").getAsString();
        url = new URL(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token="
                        + access_token);
        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        outputString = "";
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlConn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            outputString += line;
        }
        System.out.println(outputString);
```

Comment: Sir i have tried it not working. I have replaced it with mine credentials but still  no progress. Now, I am trying to implement through js.

Comment: are you asking in js?

Comment: no after implemented the code i suggest what is the error?